# Windows hotspot without publishing SSID

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, hotspot

I want to create a WiFi hotspot with my Windows machine. I have created it using command:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=myspot key=H)TP1ss
```

But it is publishing its SSID to all the devices. Is it possible to hide the SSID, and allow connections?

Comment: Please note that hiding the SSID does not provide any increase in security.

Comment: @DanielB security is fine. I just wanted to hide the ssid.

Answer (score 2):

Looking [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890(v=ws.10).aspx), there is no mention of being able to hide the SSID of a Windows Soft AP.

As such, it would appear there is no implemented way to do this. Additionally, Connectify, software which builds upon the Hosted Network functionality in Windows, states they cannot do this due to missing implementation [here](http://support.connectify.me/article/27-can-i-hide-my-network-name-or-ssid):

> ### Can I hide my network name or SSID?
>
> There have been many user requests for this feature and Connectify
>   would like to be able to offer this option, but unfortunately we
>   cannot. Connectify Hotspot uses the Windows Hosted Network feature to
>   make wireless networks, and Hosted Network has no option for hiding
>   the SSID / not broadcasting. Offering the Hidden SSID feature is not
>   possible with the current implementation of Hotspot.